# Android spinner populating using arraylist<string>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

im to populate spinner using arraylist , and that arraylist actully holds data from the file having android application data stored already for t=my application,
 im pasting the code  ,, problem is spinner populates but values appear twice

```
     String[] wee = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
     final String[] str={"Report 1","Report 2","Report 3","Report 4","Report 5"};
     ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
     spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

     for(int i = 0;i < wee.length; i++){
         spinnerArrayAdapter.add(wee[i]+"\n");
         spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     // Spinner spinYear = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin);
     spin.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Please run your question through an English grammar and vocabulary checker.

Answer (score 14):

Try to initialize your spinner adapter with array in constructor.

```
String[] wee = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
final String[] str={"Report 1","Report 2","Report 3","Report 4","Report 5"};
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
         this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, wee);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

// Spinner spinYear = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin);
spin.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: its not working !(http://tinypic.com/usermedia.php?uo=a6BMdyuA%2FVxnXZc9K8Flooh4l5k2TGxc#.UpbQRsSkpXs) see

Comment: Are you sure that in `list2` you don't have duplicated values ?

Comment: list2 is empty and its an arrayList of type string , im populating it dynamicaly using hashmap that is getting values from file String CurData="";      for (int i=0; i < ListMaps.size();i++){HashMap<String, String> map=ListMaps.get(i);
           CurData =CurData+map.get("bmi")+"\n";
            }    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(); for(int i=0;i<ListMaps.size();i++){  list2.add(CurData);}
        String[] wee = list2.toArray(new ring[list2.size()]);
     ...and then the spinner code i pasted already

Comment: Can you run it through debug mode and check what is in `list2`?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void setSpinner() {
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_size);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    ArrayList<String> sizes = null;

    if (intent != null) {
      // Receiving ArrayList in Another Activity where "sizeList" is the Key
        sizes = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("SizeList");
    }

    if (sizes != null) {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sizes);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Spinner click listener
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


}
```

*Call setSpinner() method from OnCreate() Method. You can directly pass ArrayList as a parameter, you don't need to convert into String[].*